# Dynamic controller pass to ng-template

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've been trying to improve myself on angularjs so i've started a project with angularjs in it. But i got stuck ...

I'm trying to ng-repeat some html elements using **controller1.modalItems**. Within the html template like below, i also want to dynamically add another template.

```
<div ng-repeat="li in modalItems">
  <div ng-include="test.html"></div>
  <div class="head">{{li.title}}</div>
</div>
```

here is the **test.html**

```
<script type="text/ng-template" src="test.html">

            <ul >
                  <li ng-repeat="t in items">
                   <img src="{{ t.img }}" alt="" title="" />
                  </li>
            </ul>

</script>
```

how can i pass the controller that it needs to repeated to **test.html** template.

Comment: depends on that you are trying to use controller for....using a directive might fit your situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can pass the controller using `ng-controller` directive:

```html
<div ng-include="test.html" ng-controller="theController"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do that

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngController

> A common mistake is to declare the controller again using ng-controller in the template itself. This will cause the controller to be attached and executed twice.